# angular().service() wont get a update in the object I pass as parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, ngtable

Well fist time here, so sorry for the mess or the long text.

I pass **$scope.alertsensorconfigs** as **tableData** to my service, and wen I delete a item, my **$scope.alertsensorconfigs** changes but wen It try to reload the table I see that **tableData** had not changed.

*Detailed explanation:*

I have a site that uses NgTable to create a lot of tables in different pages, but all the logic to convert and filter the data that I want to show in the page was coded in the pages and it repeated a lot of times but it was working, so i decided to thy make a service that do all that.

So my problem is, I created the service, it i almost all working like before, but I notices that wen I delete a item from the table, it deletes the data but keep showing it on the table until I reload the page.

I notice that it is because even that my object on the page have changed after delete, wen it is inside my service the object apear to be the unchanged one, since I passed my object as parameter to my service i took it wold pass like a reference to the object and wen it changes on the page it wold apear changed in my service, but looks like it is not the case, it looks like wen it calls for the fist time my service it makes a copy of my object and wen it calls again it wont get the updated one.

My page code.

```
$scope.funcFilter = function(pfilter){
    return function (item) {
        return item.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(pfilter) >= 0
            || 
item.criticality1.toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(pfilter) >= 0
            || 
item.criticality2.toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(pfilter) >= 0
            || $filter('translate') 
(item.active.toString().toUpperCase()).indexOf(pfilter) >= 0;
    }
}
    $scope.searchTable = {filter: ""};
    $scope.tableParams = 
NgTableDataService.getGenericTableParams($scope.alertsensorconfigs, 
$scope.funcFilter, $scope.searchTable.filter)
```

Delete function in my page:

```
AlertSensorConfig.remove({id: obj.id}, function () {
                $scope.alertsensorconfigs.splice($scope.alertsensorconfigs.indexOf(obj), 1);
                $scope.tableParams.reload().then(function(data) {
                    if (data.length === 0 && $scope.tableParams.total() > 0) {
                        $scope.tableParams.page($scope.tableParams.page() - 1);
                        $scope.tableParams.reload();
                    }
                });
            },
```

My service:

```
angular.module('control-room').service('NgTableDataService', 
function ($filter, NgTableParams, Session) {

    var session = Session.get();

    this.getGenericTableParams = function(tableData, funcFilter, searchTableFilter){
        return new NgTableParams({
            count: session.user.tablePagination,
            filter: searchTableFilter
        }, {
            counts: rowsPerPageTemplate,
            getData: function (params) {
                if (params.filter() == ''){
                    var pfilter = '';
                }else{
                    var pfilter = params.filter().filter.toUpperCase();
                }
                let filteredData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(tableData, funcFilter(pfilter)) : tableData;
                if (!!filteredData && filteredData.length >= 0) {
                    params.total(filteredData.length);
                    var rowsPerPageTemplateWithAllData = rowsPerPageTemplate.slice();
                    var isFound = rowsPerPageTemplateWithAllData.some(function (element) {
                        return element === filteredData.length;
                    });
                    params.settings().counts = rowsPerPageTemplateWithAllData.filter(item=>item<filteredData.length)

                    if (filteredData.length >= 5){
                     params.settings().counts.push(filteredData.length);
                    }
                    rowsPerPageTemplateWithAllData.push(filteredData.length + (isFound ? 1 : 0));  
                    if (session.user.tablePagination >= params.settings().counts[params.settings().counts.length-1]){
                        params.settings().count = params.settings().counts[params.settings().counts.length-1];
                    }else{
                        params.settings().count = session.user.tablePagination;
                    }
                    if (params.total() <= params.count()) {
                        params.page(1);
                    }
                    var x = $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy());
                    var y = x.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                    return y;
                } else {
                    params.settings().counts = [];
                    return null;
                } 
            }
        });
    };
```

And the ng-table function that reload the table after delete:

```
this.reload = function() {
            var self = this,
                pData = null;

            settings.$loading = true;

            prevParamsMemento = angular.copy(createComparableParams());
            isCommittedDataset = true;

            if (self.hasGroup()) {
                pData = runInterceptorPipeline($q.when(settings.getGroups(self)));
            } else {
                pData = runInterceptorPipeline($q.when(settings.getData(self)));
            }

            log('ngTable: reload data');

            var oldData = self.data;
            return pData.then(function(data) {
                settings.$loading = false;
                errParamsMemento = null;

                self.data = data;
                event even when data === oldData
                ngTableEventsChannel.publishAfterReloadData(self, data, oldData);
                self.reloadPages();

                return data;
            }).catch(function(reason){
                errParamsMemento = prevParamsMemento;
                // "rethrow"
                return $q.reject(reason);
            });
        };
```

there is some way to make sure the object I pas as parameter to my service is updated every time I call it, like some binding?

Comment: Please add comments to your code

Answer (score 0):

Edit : I misunderstood the question

According to your comment what you want is to update a variable in your service and retrieve it later.

What you can do is :

- In your service

  ```
  angular
      .module('app.core')
      .factory('', dataservice);

  dataservice.$inject = ['$http'];

  function dataservice($http) {
      return {
          myFunction: yourServiceFunction,
          myData: myData
      };

      var myData = [];

      function yourServiceFunction(tableData) {
          // DO SOMETHING
          myData = tableData;
          // DO SOMETHING
      }
  }
  ```

Like this you can access to `myData` in your service or in your controller which is updated in your function with the value of `tableData` that you passed when you called your function.

And if you want to update `myData` in your service everytime `$scope.alertsensorconfigs` changes, add a `$watch` to this variable and create a function in your service who is called whenever your $scope value change and which simply update `myData` in your service.

I hope that I answered to the right question this time :)

.
.
.

*Here after : old response which do not answer to the question*

> there is some way to make sure the object I pas as parameter to my service is updated every time I call it, like some binding?

Yes.

I am sorry to not answer with your code but it is a bit hard to get into it.

The simpliest way is to do something like this :

```
$scope.alertsensorconfigs =
   yourService.yourMethod($scope.alertsensorconfigs, param2, param3).tableData;
```

While your services' method does something like :

```
yourMethod = function (tableData, param2, param3) {
   // DO SOMETHING
   return { tableData : tableDataAfterModification, elem2 : 'elem2', elem3 : 'elem3' };
};
```

Comment: I tried it but it din't work, if I got it right, in this code of yours you call my service method saying that you want it to set the **$scope.alertsensorconfigs** with the return of the method (sorry if I got it wrong). But what I needed was the opposite, I wanted to set the **tableData** to **$scope.alertsensorconfigs** every time the **$scope.alertsensorconfigs** change.

Comment: Oh sorry I got it wrong. I will update my answer according to your comment hoping that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm new on programming js and angular, so I never used @watch, but I will try do it since my way solved this one problem but create another ones =/

Answer (score 0):

I think i manage to solve it.

The NgTable have his own reload(), but it wasn't working because what it does is, get the current **filteredData** and replace with the one **tableData**, but the **tableData** on my service was only set wen it was called the fist time and wasn't getting  updated wen I updated the **$scope.alertsensorconfigs**.

So what I manage to do after a lot of headache, was to create in my service:
A var **serviceTableData** that receives the **$scope.alertsensorconfigs** wen the service is called so it is global in my service.
And my own reload() function that I replaced in every place that my controller used the NgTable reload().

My service reload() wen called receives as parameter from the controller the **$scope.alertsensorconfigs** after the controller delete or edit the item, then it will set the **serviceTableData** to the updated data received as param and then calls the NgTable reload().

So it ended like this:

```
angular.module().service('NgTableDataService', 
function ($filter, NgTableParams, Session, MY_CONSTANTS) {

    var session = Session.get();
    var serviceTableParam = null;
    var serviceTableData = null;

    this.reloadTableData = function (tableDataAtt){
        serviceTableData = tableDataAtt;
        serviceTableParam.reload().then(function(data) {
            if (data.length === 0 && serviceTableData.total() > 0) {
                serviceTableParam.page(serviceTableParam.page() - 1);
                serviceTableParam.reload();
            }
        return this.tableData = tableDataAtt;
        });   
    };

    this.getGenericTableParams = function(tableData, searchTableFilter, funcFilter){

        serviceTableData = tableData;
        return serviceTableParam = new NgTableParams({
        // etc...
```